# simplify massive same php conditions

Tags: php, templates, if-statement, printf

I have a question, I wonder what is the best way to print many different strings depending a language, I mean, today I have sthg simple :

```
function getStringA($lang,$data1,$data2){
   if($lang=='en'){return 'my string is '.$data1.' and '.$data2;}
   elseif($lang=='fr'){return 'ma chaine est '.$data1.' et '.$data2;}
   elseif($lang=='it'){return $data1.'blabla '.$data2.' blabla';}
   ..
   [50 conditions]
}

function getStringB($lang,$data){
    [same 50 conditions, one per language]
}

function getStringC($lang,$data){
  ..
}
...
```

and then :

```
echo getStringA('en','test','test1');
echo getStringB('en','AAAA');
echo getStringB('en','BBBB');
..
```

1. there is always those same 50 languages conditions on each function
2. the place of data parameters can change in the string (at the end, middle..)

I thought to use printf but I don't know if it will be really better, I need sthg fast and most important, easy to maintain.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Put your strings into array and change concatenation into `printf()-alike` function format:

```
$stringsA = array(
    'en' => 'my string is %s and %s',
    'fr' => 'ma chaine est %s et %s',
    // ...
);
```

Then in your function get text by array key:

```
function getStringA($lang,$data1,$data2){
    return isset($stringsA[$lang])? vprintf($stringsA[$lang], array($data1, $data2)) : '';
}
```

You can also use your own placeholders in strings and `str_replace()` function:

```
// e.g. 'my string is {propery} and {secondProperty}'


function getStringA($lang,$data1,$data2){
    return isset($stringsA[$lang])? str_replace(array('{propery}', '{secondProperty}'), array($data1, $data2), $stringsA[$lang]) : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not an array?

```
$conditions = ['en' => 'foo', 'fr' => 'bar', etc...]

if (isset($conditions[$lang])) {
   return $conditions[$lang];
} else {
   return $default_value;
}
```

Comment: and how do you pass parameters?

Comment: another function to build the string, probably. but this is how you'd get away from a 50-item if/else/else/else/else/......../else chain

Answer (score -1):

Use arrays and to pass params you can use [vsprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) function

```
$translate = [
  'en' => [
     'my_string_is' => 'my string is %s and %s';
  ],
  'fr' => [
     'my_string_is' => 'ma chaine est %s et %s';
  ]
];

function translate ($translations, $word, $lang, array $params = []) {
   return isset($translations[$lang][$word]) ? vsprintf($translations[$lang][$word], $params) : $word;
}

// usage

echo translate($translations, 'my_string_is' ,'en', ['wordA', 'wordB']);
echo translate($translations, 'my_string_is' ,'fr', ['wordA', 'wordB']);
```

This is very basic idea. It can be written better. Translation can be held in config files like ini, xml, yaml etc also it could be written in OOP so it would be better to use.

Comment: it's not just to return translated strings, it's how to build a string with parameters using languages templates (the place of parameters can change in the string, depending the language)

Comment: thanks but very heavy, I finally found a trick, please read my answer

Comment: not so heavy but flexible. Maybe passing array as first param is not good but I did not want to use globals or static array.